# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in

Tags: php

When I run this script (http://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/sharrre.php?url=https://bizonbytes.com&type=googlePlus):

```
<?php
  //Sharrre by Julien Hany
  $json = array('url'=>'','count'=>0);
  $json['url'] = $_GET['url'];
  $url = urlencode($_GET['url']);
  $type = urlencode($_GET['type']);

  if(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    if($type == 'googlePlus'){  //source http://www.helmutgranda.com/2011/11/01/get-a-url-google-count-via-php/
      $content = parse("https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".$url."&count=true");

      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
      @$dom->loadHTML($content);
      $domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
      $newDom = new DOMDocument;
      $newDom->formatOutput = true;

      $filtered = $domxpath->query("//div[@id='aggregateCount']");
      $json['count'] = str_replace('>', '', $filtered->item(0)->nodeValue);
    }
    else if($type == 'stumbleupon'){
      $content = parse("http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=$url");

      $result = json_decode($content);
      $json['count'] = $result->result->views;
      if( !isset($json['count']) ) $json['count'] = 0;
    }
    else if($type == 'pinterest'){
      $content = parse("http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=&url=$url");

      $result = json_decode(str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('', ''), $content));
      $json['count'] = $result->count;
      if( !isset($json['count']) ) $json['count'] = 0;
    }
  }
  echo str_replace('\\/','/',json_encode($json));

  function parse($encUrl){
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'sharrre', // who am i
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5, // timeout on connect
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, // timeout on response
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3, // stop after 10 redirects
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $encUrl;  
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($errmsg != '' || $err != '') {
      /*print_r($errmsg);
      print_r($errmsg);*/
    }
    return $content;
  }
?>
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\bizonbytes.com\httpdocs\miscellaneous\sharrre.php on line 56
{"url":"https://bizonbytes.com","count":""}
```

**Important notes**

- I have NO experience with PHP I just need to run this script
  (sharrre.php)
- I've look at other similar case but could figure out the problem.
- I have open the windows/php.ini and made sure that safe_mode = Off
- I Notice that open_basedir is set like this ;open_basedir =
- Do I need to add something in the open_basedir?
- This is the link for the detail info about the php version installed. See http://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/test.php

Thanks everyone for your help in that matter

Comment: PHP can have multiple .ini files and various levels at which ini-type overrides can be performed. Run a `phpinfo()` somewhere within that script of yours to see what the actual local in-effect settings are.

Comment: @MarcB when you run http://bizonbytes.com/miscellaneous/test.php you get I think that info.

Answer (score 10):

Please note that this is a security warning. Using cURL, a website could redirect the script to something like `file:///etc/passwd` and mess with things around. To prevent this, whenever open_basedir is set cURL doesn't follow locations. You'll have to follow them manually, and manually check if all followed locations are safe as well.

[This comment on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121) implements a sample implementation of that:

```
function curl_exec_follow(/*resource*/ $ch, /*int*/ &$maxredirect = null) {
    $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        if ($mr > 0) {
            $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

            $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            do {
                curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
                $header = curl_exec($rch);
                if (curl_errno($rch)) {
                    $code = 0;
                } else {
                    $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
                        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
                        $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
                    } else {
                        $code = 0;
                    }
                }
            } while ($code && --$mr);
            curl_close($rch);
            if (!$mr) {
                if ($maxredirect === null) {
                    trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.', E_USER_WARNING);
                } else {
                    $maxredirect = 0;
                }
                return false;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
        }
    }
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: i don't buy this as a reasonable solution.

Comment: I just tried it and it works great. Thank you for posting it.

Comment: I've taken the preg_match part and a similar setup i already had in my code for resolving urls and works like a charm :)

Comment: It just shows how stupid PHP configurations are. I'm a PHP developer for more than 5 years and had never heard about this. It's not security, its stupidity. It should be better to block redirections to local files, or curl module should implement a function like this. It should not be a user function.

Comment: It's a limitation on how cURL and PHP interacts. cURL is external to PHP and bound through an extension. There are several abstraction layers built on top of it that already fixes the problem, the curl_* API is not a high-level one.