# Flash REST woes: passing headers through php proxy

Tags: php, flash, http, rest, proxy

I'm writing ActionScript3 flash game, which needs to access REST services specified by sponsor  (buyer of game) - things like highscores etc. I know how to use URLLoader, URLRequest, set URLRequestHeader.

Unfortunately sponsor is on shared hosting and can't put crossdomain.xml in the server root, so I can't connect to it from my localhost flash game ([Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). I learned that there is a way to connect to rest API by proxying calls through a php file on a different server.

So I have a proxy.php file on my private server, and am calling it like:

```
www.myserver.pl/scripts/proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2sponsorserver.hosting.com/api/init.json
                                  (url=URLEncoded address)
```

It connects (returns HTTP 200), however I don't know yet how to pass custom headers to the init.json script; I tried all combinations sending them through GET and POST, as well as calling script through GET and POST (using RESTClient FF extension).

This is the proxy.php:

```
$getvars = 'myparam1=3;&myparam2=data;'; // for test purposes
$url = $_GET['url'] . '?' . $getvars;
$session = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec_follow($session);

echo $response;

curl_close($session);
```

Unfortunately my server has base_dir != '' so I can't set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and use curl_exec, hence the curl_exec_follow (taken from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835824/2492808). Could it be why the GET variables are not picked up by the init.json? It says it doesn't see the myparam1 and myparam2. Unfortunately I can't change php.ini on my server, and need a way to make it working, so that I can integrate and test sponsor's rest API from my IDE. Thanks!

**EDIT**: that was stupid, it's not the GET variables that I want to send to sponsor script, but http headers. So I've removed $getvars and added:

```
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('myparam1=3','myparam2=data'));
```

before curl_exec_follow and inside, before every new curl_exec call, which theoretically should set the headers and make them through. Unfortunately, script still doesn't see the headers :(

Also, according to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), I tried removing base_opendir restriction by putting .htaccess in www.myserver.pl/scripts/:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value open_basedir ""
</IfModule>
```

But it's not changing anything, probably I don't have

> "AllowOverride Options" or "AllowOverride All" privileges to do so

so CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is still illegal.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately I can't change php.ini on my server, and need a way to make it working, so that I can integrate and test sponsor's rest API from my IDE. Thanks!

Useless excuse these days. Buy a $15 per month server hosted on the amazon cloud. It's easier to spend $15 than to spend an hour writing code for an easily solvable problem. You were probably spending $10 anyway on a shared hosting plan.

Comment: This answer isn't really helpful, nor polite (was worse before Undo's edit). Other than that, I am satisfied with my server, been using it almost 2 years. And - changing server on sponsor side doesn't fix the issue, as can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704786/flash-rest-json-connecting-to-remote-server-error-2032