# How to get true address of a shortened URL in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, url, url-shortener

Is there any way that I can get the URL pointed by another (shortened) URL?
For example, I have shortened http://www.stackoverflow.com to this URL: http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2

I need a function in PHP like:

```
getTrueURL($shortened_url)
{
 // ?
}
```

That should return `'http://stackoverflow.com'` when `getTrueURL('http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2')` is called. How can I do this?

**P.S:**
If it is impossible in server-side, I can also use a JavaScript solution as well.

Comment: http://unshort.me/api.html

Comment: Thanks Mark! And all the other answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need this one:

```
<?php
function getTrueURL($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $data = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $data["url"];
}

echo getTrueURL("http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2");
?>
```

Comment: seems great, but it echoes "http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2" after giving the warning 
`curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set`. I'm on a web host, so I cannot change php configuration..

Comment: Oh I solved it by the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835255/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated-when-safe-mode-is-enabled-or-an-open

And now it echoes stackoverflow.com. Thanks!!

Comment: I deleted my half answer because this is much better. +1 because I didn't even know "curl_getinfo" existed.

Comment: hey, can I use this for google urls? like this one : https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asd.com%2F&ei=5GoPUpPNLIjMtAbP8YDgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHsaOHf1rJt1wFRnD6eT7al-DocHQ&sig2=QkCTusHlq-4NePlGUFfsrQ&bvm=bv.50768961,d.Yms

Comment: you can use `parse_url` for it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php



function tinyurl_reverse($szAddress)
{
    $szAddress = explode('.com/', $szAddress);
    $szAddress = 'http://preview.tinyurl.com/'.$szAddress[1];
    $szDocument = file_get_contents($szAddress);
    preg_match('~redirecturl" href="(.*)">~i', $szDocument, $aMatches);

    if(isset($aMatches[1]))
    {
        return $aMatches[1];
    }

    return null;
}

echo tinyurl_reverse('http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2');
?>
```

Comment: I need a general way, not only for tinyurl. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: there is no 'general way' because all those services use their own algorithm. "URL shortening" is not a part of the internet URL protocols.

Comment: If you want a generic solution, then try the unshort.me API that I posted as a comment to your question: it claims to work with  t.co (Twitter), bit.ly, TinyURL, Google goo.gl, Facebok fb.me, tr.im, Ow.ly and others