# How to redirect to follow a posted url using curl

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have

```
<?php



$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('emailID' => $_POST['emailID'], 'mobileNo' => $_POST['mobileNo'],'orderID'=>$_POST['orderID'],'amount'=>$_POST['amount']);



 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
 CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.ppai.com/p/api/secure/pay/',
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>array ('X-API-KEY:123456789'),
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data ,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE

 ));

 $response = curl_exec($ch) ;
// //echo $response ;
?>
```

But im getting a warning that

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set
```

and after a form post this php shoudl redirect me to this url but instead its loading in the same url.

Comment: Seems like you are running PHP on safe-mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835255/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated-when-safe-mode-is-enabled-or-an-open

Comment: Warning says it all, a bit googling won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the warning states..

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled
>   or an open_basedir is set

There must be two cases for this..

### 1.

The safe mode must have been enabled, You need to disable it by doing the below step.

Open your `php.ini` search for `safe_mode` and Change the On to Off

```
safe_mode = Off
```

and save the file, restart your webserver.

### 2.

If that doesn't work, then the `open_basedir` must have been assigned some value.. You need to uncomment it.

Open your `php.ini` search for `open_basedir` and add a seimcolon before it.

```
;open_basedir =
```

and save the file, restart your webserver.

Comment: This is the answer for the question actually since this is source of the problem.

Comment: FYI I cant put that huge content under a comment.

Comment: now you have edited the content. before it was only **3** lines and you can't put that in comment ?

Comment: You need to give time for others to edit the answer and I am not a robot to type everything at once. You can't hardly answer that question but you are ready to criticize on the first place.

Comment: @AncientGeek Shankar's initial answer was fully qualified to be an answer for this particular question.